# AngularJS Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider - $modalInstanceProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a button that you click and it is supposed to open a modal onclick. However, when I click the button I get the error "Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance". I checked everything so far. What am I missing? Here is the code so far.

app. js - loading the ui-bootstrap.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

services.js - This is the modal service.

```
app.factory('modalService',['$uibModal', function($uibModal){
return {
  openMenuModal: function(index, title, description) {
    var modalObj = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'partials/modal.html',
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: true,
      size: 'sm',
      controller: function($scope, $modalInstance){
        $scope.title = title;
        $scope.description = description;

        $scope.ok = function(id){
          $modalInstance.close(); 
        }
        $scope.cancel = function(){
          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }
       }
    });
  }
};
}]);
```

Home Controller

```
app.controller('home', [
'$scope', 
'contentService', 
'$http',
'$uibModal', 
'modalService', function($scope, contentService, $http, $uibModal, modalService){

contentService.then(function(data){
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.shortcutList = $scope.data.shortcuts;  // list of shortcuts
    $scope.name = $scope.data.user;               // user's name
    $scope.userThumb = $scope.data.userThumb;     // user thumbnail image


    $scope.deleteBox = function(index, title, description){
        modalService.openMenuModal('t', title, description);
    };
});

}]);
```

modal template

```
<div ng-controller="Home">
  <div class="modalBox animated fadeIn">
    <h1> {{title}} </h1>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <div class="modal-footer"></div>    
 </div>
 </div>
```

shortcut template button - This is where I want to call the deleteBox()

```
<button class="btn btn-primary deleteBox" ng-click="deleteBox($index,  'Are You sure you want to delete this?', 'description text')"></button>
```

Comment: Can you mark an answer correct please so people know what fixed this problem=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use $uibModalInstance instead of $modalInstance.

Also in your html you put `ng-controller="Home"` and in your js file you declared the controller as `home` so you need to fix this so the names match.

Comment: Thanks. I would have not noticed the 'home' error. I inserted the `$uibModalInstance` and now I get "Access Restricted to URI denied".

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it. I wasn't loading the correct cdn. Everything else worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `$uibModalInstance` instead of `$modalInstance`

Comment: there is nothing specified as $modalInstance in https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

rather the doc says 

`controller (Type: function|string|array, Example: MyModalController) -... Has a special $uibModalInstance injectable to access the modal instance.`

Comment: Yes, this worked great! Thanks for your assistance. I also changed my cdn to the version that included templates and it worked great.

Comment: i was expecting that my answer is correct? never mind things happen ;)

Comment: Both of you are correct. I wish I could select both!